# How do I highlight a tab in Wordpress for a post when the main menu item is a category?

Tags: wordpress, menu, categories, highlight

On my Wordpress site I have the main primary menu set up with links to pages & top level categories. When I'm viewing a page the top menu highlights the proper menu item and all works just fine, but when I click on a post that falls under one of the category menu items it is not highlighted. I want the category menu item to highlight when I click on a post that uses that category. How would I accomplish that?

Website: http://deutschmetal.com If you click on this post: http://deutschmetal.com/deutsch-metal-videos/rammstein-herzeleid-videos/ you can see that the top menu link "***Videos***" is not highlighted. I would like it to be highlighted when viewing the post.

Comment: Add your active styles to `.current-menu-parent {...}`

Comment: Or `.current-post-ancestor`

Comment: Or `.current-post-parent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress detects it if a page is the child of a page in the navigation. It also adds a extra class to it, so you can create some new CSS to make it look the way you want. In your case this would be:

```
.current-post-parent.current-post-ancestor {
    background: #cb0808;
}
```

You can add this in your Wordpress theme, or if you are not familiar with coding you can use the customizer's custom CSS that is supported is most of the themes.

Comment: That works to a point. When I click on other posts that are not part of the videos area it highlights two tabs that are side by side instead of the one it should. If you go to http://deutschmetal.com/gallery/rammstein-east-rutherford-2011/ you can see that it has two tabs lit up. About is a page and gallery is a category.

Comment: Hmm... Don't know why that is happening. But there is a workaround for this. We can add .current-post-ancestor to the class. I have edited my answer above. Tested it, and it works.

Comment: I have another related question to this. As I've added some drop down items the tabs of those items are not highlighting. I added a suggestion from above and change the CSS to: `.current-post-parent.current-post-ancestor.current-menu-parent {
    background: #cb0808;
}` but the tabs don't highlight when on a drop down menu item. http://deutschmetal.com/deutsch-metal-news/ is the drop down of the Home tab. This link is also a category.

Comment: Just for reference I fixed this myself so if someone else comes along they can see the fix. To fix this I needed this CSS instead: `.current-post-parent, .current-post-ancestor, .current-menu-parent {
    background: #cb0808;
}`